# Xamarin form - Can't connect to SignalR with url https (Not working on iOS but works on Android)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, signalr

```
 try
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx")
                .Build();
            _connection.On<string, string>("", OnSend);
            await _connection.StartAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
private void OnSend(string name, string message)
    {
        //Log(Color.Black, name + ": " + message);
    }
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 ver 15.8.0 preview 5.0 pair to mac mini ver 10.13.3
And run on iphonesimulator

Got the following Exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest+<RunWithTimeoutWorker>d__241`1[T].MoveNext () [0x000b5] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.11/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:952 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00018] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.11/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1180 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.11/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:550 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.11/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.11/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.11/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.14.0.11/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x003d3] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:402 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: post your WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder code. Is firewall blocking access?

Comment: public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .UseStartup<Startup>();

Comment: server client and mac are turn off firewall already

Comment: where do you configure the URL? how do you run the server? do you use [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)?

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem by run server on another one

Comment: ok, post an answer with the additional steps/code you needed to add to fix the issue.